# ¿Como insertar el numero 0 si un radioButton no esta seleccionado? con PHP Y SQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo el siguiente formulario:

```
<form action="exed.php" name="formAct1" id="formAct1" method="POST">
 input type="radio" name="sintoma_1" value="1">
 <button type="submit">enviar</button>
</form>
```

Este formulario al enviarlo se redirige al archivo exed.php, donde tengo esto:

```
<?php

require_once '../../../connections/forum.php';
$connection = new forum();

$connection->upd($_POST);

//header('Location: index.php');

?>
```

Despues llamo la funcion upd y esta funcion esta compuesta por esto:

```
 public function upd($data)
    {    
        $conexion = new Connection();
        $pdo = $conexion->getConexion();
        $statement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE user SET apetencia_a1s3 = :sintoma_1 WHERE ".$_SESSION['id_user']." ");
        $statement->bindValue('sintoma_1', $data['sintoma_1']);
        $res = $statement->execute();
    }
```

Lo que quiero es que si no esta seleccionado entonces que mande un 0 a mi consulta, es decir que se actualice el numero 0 en dicho campo.
¿Es posible hacerlo?

Comment: Esto podría considerarse también un problema de UX... ¡Los radio buttons no están hechos para dejarse vacíos! ¡El motivo por el que elegirías un radiobutton sobre un check es porque esperas UNA respuesta de una coleccion de opciones! Si bien no está mal verificar la entrada en el backend de tu aplicación, establecerlo si no está seleccionado no debería ser el comportamiento esperado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creo que si lo haces así en **exed.php** te funcionará:

```php
<?php

require_once '../../../connections/forum.php';
$connection = new forum();

if(!isset($_POST['sintoma_1'])) {
    $_POST['sintoma_1'] = "0";
}

$connection->upd($_POST);

//header('Location: index.php');

?>
```

Básicamente comprobamos si hay un valor $_POST para ese radiobutton con [isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php), y si no lo hay entonces lo creamos con valor 0.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, correcto!